# Angular Load LinkedIn Scripts From Partial

Tags: angularjs

I am using LinkedIn API and I need to load their login scripts when my user hits a certain route. However , from what I've read in stackoverflow it is not possible to just put the script elements inside a partial . 
my code is straight forward :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.js">          
     ...
 <script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
 api_key: ...
 authorize: true
 onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="in/Login">
 Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
 </script>

 <script src="js/linkedinFuncs.js"></script>
 </div>
```

The 3 last scripts (the linkedin ones) only needs to be included when the user hits the 'login' route . Any thoughts?

Comment: did you try put your script in a partial that the router loads in the ng-view part of your page?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experiences this issue :

1)Make sure you load jquery BEFORE angular

2)Run the latest angular (this issue is resolved on 1.2.9 but was unresolved for me on 1.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

You could load it from the code in your relevant congtroller programmatically by using something like this

```
        (function injectScript() {
            var src = 'http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js',
                script = document.createElement('script');
            script.async = true;


            script.src = src;
            var api_key = 'YOUR_KEY_HERE';
            //script.authorize = true;
            script.text = 'api_key: ' + api_key + '\n' + 'authorize: true\n';
            script.onload = function() {
                IN.Event.on(IN, 'systemReady', function() {

                    loadDeferred.resolve(IN);
                });
            };

            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
        })();
```